# How Do I Display Additional Detail On User Hover Card

Tags: chatter, user-record

I want to show the city on the hoover card in the chatter app when my users hoover over the name. Anyone know how i fix that?

[image: Ninja hoover card]

Answer (score 2):

What I am expecting being displayed when hovering an user is the related mini page layout. This can be customised at **Customize - Users - Page Layouts**. This opens a list with all existing layouts for User object. Edit the layout you want to modify. There is a link to modify the mini page layout on the top bar.

[image: Mini Page Layout Link]

However, when I tried to open it, I noticed standard fields are not selectable fields for the layout (still wondering why).

I would suggest creating a custom formula field on User pointing to Standard City field, then selecting it to be displayed on the mini page layout. That would do the trick.

Hope it helps.